# Obtain a reference to rendered elements in React

Tags: reactjs, next.js, svelte

currently i want to implement this function from svelte to react,
is this possible implement it?

Documentation: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/bind-this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It already exists in react and its called 'ref'.

You can refer to the documentation https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref